# Possibility of changing report header to page header in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Is there a possibility of changing existing report header section into page header?

Comment: No, but you can select all section objects and copy-paste these into different section.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: I have already done this in longer way. I had report with 7-8 report header sections, each with diffrent configuration in Section Expert. I had to change those sections into page header sections. In my case it didn't took much time but if i woud have more files like this (it can happen in my close future) it can be very time-consuming. Sorry for my poor grammar and tl;dr